# Remove first and last char from string

Tags: php, trim

I have this:

```
$dataList = "*one*two*three*";
$list = explode("*", $dataList);
echo"<pre>";print_r($list);echo"</pre>";
```

which outputs:

```
> Array (
>     [0] => 
>     [1] => one
>     [2] => two
>     [3] => three
>     [4] =>  )
```

How do I strip the fist and last * in the string before exploding?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Using [`trim`](http://php.net/trim):

```
trim($dataList, '*');
```

This will remove all `*` characters (even if there are more than one!) from the end and the beginning of the string.

Comment: saras javab aapyo!

Answer (score 58):

Some other possibilities:

Using substr:

```
$dataList = substr($dataList, 1, -1);
```

You can also choose to not remove the * from the string but rather remove the empty array values which will always be the first and last element.
Using array functions array_pop() and array_shift():

```
$arrData = array_pop(array_shift($arrData));
```

Comment: Second part is incorrect and results in an error. `array_pop` and `array_shift` modify the array itself (return value for both is the element they remove), so you simply need to do `array_shift($arrData); array_pop($arrData);`

Answer (score 20):

`$string = substr($dataList, 1, -1);`

Remove the first and the last character of the string in php

Answer (score 7):

```
trim($dataList, "*")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo trim($dataList,"*");
```

hope this solve your problem